# node.js axios request with cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, axios

so i have browser(netscape?) cookie like that [nscookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nbry.png)
or JSON cookie like [jsoncookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH1yR.png)

How should i pass this into [request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5i5y.png)?

code source:

```
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    axios = require('axios');

function reqTest()
{

    axios.default.request({
        'url': 'google.com',
        'method': 'post',
        'headers':
            {
                'Cookie': 'cookie1=?; cookie2=?;'
            }
    }
    ).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having the `withCredentials` key enabled (set to 'true') should solve your issue.

Please try this:

```
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    axios = require('axios');

function reqTest()
{

    axios.default.request({
        'url': 'google.com',
        'method': 'post',
        'headers':
            {
                'Cookie': 'cookie1=?; cookie2=?;'
            },
        'withCredentials': 'true' // ADD THIS LINE
    }
    ).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

You can also enable this property for all requests in this instance of axios, changing axios' defaults:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.post(url, body).then(...).catch(...); // withCredentials is automatically enabled
```

Please report results.

Comment: yep, this option is really needed, but i still cant find information about how can i put netscape-format cookie into axios request body

Comment: i do not understand how it works at all, i have a login cookie that can auth me into account,like session cookie,  and i need to make request with that cookie to get an html doc like im logged into account