# Pass cookie with axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, axios

I'm trying to pass a cookie (which was set in the browser (e. g. Edge V102.0.1245.44 or Firefox V89.0.2)) by an axios request to another server (which is on the same host = localhost). I still tried a lot of different settings, but none did work. **The cookie seems to be existing in the express request (`http://localhost:3000/request`)** `req.headers.cookie`.

See:

[Make Axios send cookies in its requests automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically)

[node.js axios request with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004942/node-js-axios-request-with-cookies)

[Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests)

[How to set cookies when send a request in node ?](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/943)

Here is an example what I tried:

Send request `http://localhost:3000/request`, cookie is set before by `http://localhost:3000/setcookie`:

```
const express = require('express')
import { Request, Response } from "express"
const axios = require('axios')
const dayjs = require('dayjs')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/setcookie', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const cookieName = 'cookie-name'
  const cookieValue = dayjs().format('HH:mm:ss DD.MM.YYYY')
  res.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
  res.send(`Cookie successfully set:  ${cookieName}=${cookieValue}`);
});

let content = `Hello world`

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.cookies)
  console.log(req.headers.cookie)
  res.send(content)
})

app.get('/request', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.cookies)
  console.log(req.headers.cookie)
  let url = 'http://localhost:2999'
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
    console.log(result.headers)
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  res.send(true)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Request is send to:

```
const express = require('express')
import { Request, Response } from "express"
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express()
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: "http://localhost",
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Content-Type',
    'Authorization',
  ],
}));

const port = 2999
    
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.headers)
  console.log(req.cookies)
  res.send(true)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Do you need more information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different HTTP clients involved here:

- The http://localhost:3000/setcookie request is made by your browser and the browser stores the cookie.
- The http://localhost:2999 request is made by your Node.js process, which knows nothing about the browser's cookies.

You would have to copy the cookies from the incoming request into the outgoing (axios) request, perhaps so:

```js
axios.get(url, {
  headers: {cookie: req.headers.cookie}
})
```

Neither `withCredentials: true` nor CORS settings are needed in this case, because both are relevant only if the HTTP client is a *browser*.

Comment: I thought when the cookie is present in the current request, it should be also availabe in the axios request?
When adding the cookie manally to axios request I do not need `withCredentials: true` or the cors settings in the receiving server `localhost:2999`. The cookie is just send without any of those settings. So is this way just correct in case of security?

Comment: You won't need `withCredentials` in that case, and won't need CORS either. See my edited answer.

Comment: Axios 1.3.4 (using Test Cafe) gives an error and does not set a cookie: Argument type { headers: { cookie: string } } is not assignable to parameter type axios.AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined